# Why is a Chrome extension trying to send email from my machine without my permission?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

While using the Chrome dev tools, I noticed this error thrown by a Chrome extension:

```
Being Called
chrome-extension://pgphcomnlaojlmmcjmiddhdapjpbgeoc/mailto.js:55Got message from bg page - https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1
chrome-extension://pgphcomnlaojlmmcjmiddhdapjpbgeoc/mailto.js:24Starting to rewrite mailtos
```

It looks like it's trying to use my gmail account to send out emails without notifying me - is that possible?

Comment: it looks like that's the chrome extension for using gmail when you click on mailto links. It's over my head but I googled those lines and found the same errors at the bottom of this page: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-com-and-sizzlejs-are-used-in-many-malware-redirects-can-you-make-it-stop ...possibly some malware is using your email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try configuring and/or outright disabling the *Send from Gmail* extension. You can also ask the author at [its page](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/pgphcomnlaojlmmcjmiddhdapjpbgeoc).

Answer (score 1):

Open your Chrome browser, type chrome://extensions into your address bar and hit Enter. Disable the option "Send from GMail".

I got the same error as you when I was debugging my own AngularJS application via JetBrains WebStorm I wonder if it isn't using the GMail extension to report usage statistics, which I agreed to when I installed the app.

You might have a similar scenario.